# Sharepoint and SSRS query issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 with Sharepoint 2010 list and I have two reports from same SharePoint list. They return the same thing, only diffrence is the filtering part.

How can we check in a CAML query if `Program` parameter is empty then run below part?

Qeuries are as follow:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ListName>HealthData</ListName>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="ReportingDate1" />
<FieldRef Name="Program" />
<FieldRef Name="Project" />
<FieldRef Name="Package" />
<FieldRef Name="DataProvider" />
<FieldRef Name="Parameter" />
<FieldRef Name="InternalPlanned_x002f_Raised" />
<FieldRef Name="InternalActual_x002f_Closed" />
<FieldRef Name="Note" />
</ViewFields>
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
     <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Program" />
      <Value Type="Text">
        <Parameter Name="Program" />
      </Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Package" />
      <Value Type="Text">
        <Parameter Name="Package" />
      </Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
 </Where>
 </Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

HealthData

Answer (score 0):

assign a parameter CAML query is mistaken, assign parameter as below

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
     <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Program" />
      <Value Type="Text">**=Parameters!ProgramName.Value**
      </Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Package" />
      <Value Type="Text">**=Parameters!PackageName.Value**
      </Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
 </Where>
 </Query>
```